# Vibrate in BroadcastReceiver in Android Q

Tags: android, notifications, android-10.0, android-vibration

I have created an alarm app years ago, it vibrates in background (while app is closed), using Alarm and BroadcastReceiver.

But now in Android Q (v10), I can't start vibrate from background and I should run a foreground service. The new problem is if device is locked and screen is off, sometimes system decides to hold/freeze the foreground service until screen is turned on by user, then it will vibrate, maybe minutes after real alarm time!

Is there any trick to vibrate without running a foreground service?

Comment: My guess is that Google wants you to use a notification, so the user has control over the behavior via the Settings app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I use Context.startForegroundService in my receiver to start service, is it possible Android system postpones starting for a while? If yes can I push it to run immediately?